# How to remove HTML code from JavaScript/jQuery logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a standard process for removing html code from jQuery code ?

Often I encounter code such as :

```
var $lab = $('<label/>').html('Enter Name ');   
var $text   = $('<input id="name" type ="text" />  ');
$set.append($lab);  
set.append($text);
```

I think this does not look very clean, can code like this be re-factored using AngularJS or similar type framework so there is seperation between UI and logic code ?

I could just break up the file into different .js files where each file contains a specific set of UI creation functions but this is not really solving the issue ?

Comment: What's "unclean" about it, what seems to be the problem, and why would you need it in separate .js files, not sure I understand the question ?

Comment: @adeneo but what if file contains 100's of lines of such code. Is there a standard method of breaking up this logic into logical areas.

Comment: Well, yes, you add some comments and create your own logic, or you use a object literal or something like that to create blocks of code etc.

Comment: Something like this comes to mind -> **http://jsfiddle.net/74233/**, note that jQuery internally uses `createElement()` etc. to create the elements, it just exposes an API that accepts stuff that looks like HTML and CSS to make it easier to use, if you don't like that, stick with native javascript instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to maintain HTML and JS separated. I've used two frameworks and I'm currently using one of them because I think it's great! (talking about angularjs).

**AngularJS**

AngularJS is a very useful framework that works using MVC patterns:
https://angularjs.org/

With this framework you process the data and do all the tough work with JS and then inject that data directly to the HTML.
You should take a look, although it's a little bit hard at the beginning.

Html Templates based frameworks, like **Backbone**

Backbone is another MVC js framework and it uses HTML templates to maintain html and js separated. You create JS classes which have a 'render' function, that paints the data (usually using templates).

http://backbonejs.org/

Of course, there are many other frameworks and ways to do it, but you could start by checking this frameworks (I especially recommend angularjs!)

Good luck :>

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs is MV* framework.
[TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) shows you the known MV* framework through a todo list application.
It covers a full bundle to make a frontend app, server-side is using to do [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Basically, an admin panel is a good place to use these frameworks.

If you simply want to separate html from js, you use a [template engine](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).

[Hogan](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) shows you how a javascript template engine works.